# creating special subgroup column in r

Tags: r

I have a large dataset with 516 rows (partial dataset below),

| Check_In | Ward_1 | Elapsed_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:18 | 2019-01-01 00:09:32 | 4.2333333 mins |
| 2019-01-01 00:11:3 | 2019-01-01 00:25:04 | 13.4500000 mins |
| 2019-01-01 00:21:33 | 2019-01-01 01:03:31 | 41.9666667 mins |
| 2019-01-01 00:27:18 | 2019-01-01 01:15:36 | 48.3000000 mins |
| 2019-01-01 01:44:07 | 2019-01-01 02:02:45 | 18.6333333 mins |
| 2019-01-01 02:10:46 | 2019-01-01 02:26:18 | 15.5333333 mins |

I would like to create a subgroup number column of 3 rows per subgroup (example below) so i can then use the qcc.groups function using the Elapsed_time and subgroup columns

| Check_In | Ward_1 | Elapsed_time | subgroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:05:18 | 2019-01-01 00:09:32 | 4.2333333 mins | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 00:11:3 | 2019-01-01 00:25:04 | 13.4500000 mins | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 00:21:33 | 2019-01-01 01:03:31 | 41.9666667 mins | 1 |
| 2019-01-01 00:27:18 | 2019-01-01 01:15:36 | 48.3000000 mins | 2 |
| 2019-01-01 01:44:07 | 2019-01-01 02:02:45 | 18.6333333 mins | 2 |
| 2019-01-01 02:10:46 | 2019-01-01 02:26:18 | 15.5333333 mins | 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another base R option

```
df$subgroup <- ceiling(seq(nrow(df)) / 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gl` from `base R` to create the group by specifying the `n` as number of rows (`nrow(df1)`) of the dataset and `k = 3`

```
df1$subgroup <- as.integer(gl(nrow(df1), 3, nrow(df1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Check_In = c("2019-01-01 00:05:18", "2019-01-01 00:11:3", 
"2019-01-01 00:21:33", "2019-01-01 00:27:18", "2019-01-01 01:44:07", 
"2019-01-01 02:10:46"), Ward_1 = c("2019-01-01 00:09:32", "2019-01-01 00:25:04", 
"2019-01-01 01:03:31", "2019-01-01 01:15:36", "2019-01-01 02:02:45", 
"2019-01-01 02:26:18"), Elapsed_time = c("4.2333333 mins", "13.4500000 mins", 
"41.9666667 mins", "48.3000000 mins", "18.6333333 mins", "15.5333333 mins"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply

```
df1 %>% mutate(grp = (row_number() +2) %/% 3)

             Check_In              Ward_1    Elapsed_time grp
1 2019-01-01 00:05:18 2019-01-01 00:09:32  4.2333333 mins   1
2  2019-01-01 00:11:3 2019-01-01 00:25:04 13.4500000 mins   1
3 2019-01-01 00:21:33 2019-01-01 01:03:31 41.9666667 mins   1
4 2019-01-01 00:27:18 2019-01-01 01:15:36 48.3000000 mins   2
5 2019-01-01 01:44:07 2019-01-01 02:02:45 18.6333333 mins   2
6 2019-01-01 02:10:46 2019-01-01 02:26:18 15.5333333 mins   2
```

`df1` dput courtesy beloved @akrun

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe: Thanks to akrun for the data.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(subgroup = rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n()))
```

Output:

```
             Check_In              Ward_1    Elapsed_time subgroup
1 2019-01-01 00:05:18 2019-01-01 00:09:32  4.2333333 mins        1
2  2019-01-01 00:11:3 2019-01-01 00:25:04 13.4500000 mins        1
3 2019-01-01 00:21:33 2019-01-01 01:03:31 41.9666667 mins        1
4 2019-01-01 00:27:18 2019-01-01 01:15:36 48.3000000 mins        2
5 2019-01-01 01:44:07 2019-01-01 02:02:45 18.6333333 mins        2
6 2019-01-01 02:10:46 2019-01-01 02:26:18 15.5333333 mins        2
```